# Apply a different theme on a per story basis storybook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components, storybook

I am making a library of react components in storybook (v6.1.14)

I have two different themes, basically and light and dark version.
I wrap all of my stories in the `<ThemeProvider>` like this:

```
import React from "react"
import {dark} from "../src/Themes/Theme";
import { ThemeProvider } from "styled-components";
import { GlobalStyles } from "../src/lib/Themes";

// apply our projects theme to our stories
const ThemeDecorator = storyFn => (
  <ThemeProvider theme={dark}>
        <GlobalStyles />
        {storyFn()}
    </ThemeProvider>
)

export default ThemeDecorator;
```

This is applied through the `preview.js` file like so:

```
const { addDecorator } = require("@storybook/react");
import ThemeDecorator from "./themeDecorator"

// Add our project theme, add a global stylesheet
addDecorator(ThemeDecorator);
```

So now everything has the dark theme applied, however, for each component I want to show two stories: One for the light theme and one for the dark theme - how do I make a story take on a different theme to the one globally declared?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as well. From the Storybook docs, I found [this answer](https://storybook.js.org/docs/riot/writing-stories/decorators#story-decorators).

So basically, you can use `decorators` with your template and apply styling to it.

```
const Template: Story<LogoProps> = (args) => {
  const { version } = args;
  return <Logo {...args} version={version} />;
};

export const Light = Template.bind({});
Light.args = {
  version: 'light',
};
Light.decorators = [
  (LightLogo) => (
    <div style={{ backgroundColor: 'black', padding: '5px 7px' }}>
      <LightLogo />
    </div>
  ),
];
```

Answer (score 0):

1. make sure your file is in TSX as this will cause typescript errors
2. follow this storybook structure for decorators

   // .storybook/preview.tsx

   ```
   import React from 'react';

   import { Preview } from '@storybook/react';

   import { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components';

   const preview: Preview = {
     decorators: [
       (Story) => (
         <ThemeProvider theme="default">
           {/*  Decorators in Storybook also accept a function. Replace <Story/> with Story() to enable it  */}
           <Story />
         </ThemeProvider>
       ),
     ],
   };

   export default preview;
   ```

> official documentation:
> https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/writing-stories/decorators